# symmetric power

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-groups, free-modules, graded-modules

Let F be a free R-module of rank r.  Prove that $\mathbb{S}_R^l(F)$ is free.  I know that this is talking about the $l^{th}$-symmetric power but how do I show it free.

Comment: What is your definition of the $l$th symmetric power?

Comment: This is from aluffi chapter 0 problem 8.4.14

Comment: Can you please write Aluffi's definition of the $l$th symmetric power so that we can understand your question without looking through the textbook?

Comment: Thats the problem.  He only defines $\mathbb{\Lambda}_R^l(M)$ as $\mathbb{\T}_R^l(M)$/W, where W is the submodule generated by all pure tensors.

Comment: That would be the definition of the antisymmetric $l$th power. However, at some point in the book, he must say what exactly he means by $\Bbb S_R^l(F)$, and I can't believe that he simply states that it's "the symmetric power" without giving a formal definition.

Comment: He just says that the symmetric power is defined similarly

Comment: Ok, that is useful information. In other words, the symmetric power is $\Bbb T^\ell_R(M)/W$, where $W$ is the submodule generated by all "commutators" $v \otimes w - w \otimes v$

Comment: Can you answer the given question then?

Comment: I suspect that the following will work: given a basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_r\}$ of $F$, show that the set
$$
S = \{f_{i_1} \vee \cdots \vee f_{i_{\ell}} : 1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_\ell \leq r\}
$$
is a basis of $\Bbb S^{\ell}_R$. It's easy to show that $S$ spans $\Bbb S^{\ell}_R$, but showing that the set is linearly independent is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to exhibit a basis of $\Bbb S_R^\ell(F)$. Given a basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_r\}$ of $F$, denote
$$
S = \{f_{i_1} \vee \cdots \vee f_{i_{\ell}} : 1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_\ell \leq r\}.
$$
It is easy to see that this set spans $\Bbb S_R^\ell(F)$. To see that it is linearly independent, it suffices to show that any choice of $\phi$

We want to show that for any function $\phi:S \to N$ for an $R$-module $N$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\bar \phi:\Bbb S_r^\ell(F)\to N$ with $\bar \phi(x) = \phi(x)$ for all $x \in S$.  By the universal property, it is equivalent to show that there exists a unique symmetric mulilinear map $\Phi:F^\ell \to N$ for which 
$$
\Phi(f_{i_1},\dots,f_{i_\ell}) = \phi(f_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes f_{i_\ell})
$$
for all choices of $1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_\ell \leq r$.

It is easy to see that if such a map exists, then this map is unique (or equivalently that the elements of $S$ span $\Bbb S_R^\ell(F)$).  It remains to be shown that any choice of $\Phi(f_{i_1},\dots,f_{i_\ell}) \in N$ can be extended to a linear map (or equivalently that the elements of $S$ are linearly independent). Indeed: if we take $n_{i_1,\dots,i_\ell} := \Phi(f_{i_1},\dots,f_{i_\ell})$, then we can define a multilinear map by 
$$
\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 
\Phi \left(\sum_{j_1=1}^r a_{1j_{1}}f_{j_1}, \dots, \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{\ell j_{\ell}}f_{j_\ell} \right) 
\\ := 
\sum_{j_1=1}^r\cdots \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{1j_{1}}\cdots a_{\ell j_{\ell}} \Phi\left(f_{j_1}, \dots,  f_{j_\ell} \right).
$$
It is clear that this function is symmetric and well defined; it now suffices to argue that this function is linear in each argument. Indeed, we can see that
$$
\Phi \left(\sum_{j_1=1}^r a_{1j_{1}}f_{j_1} + k\cdot\sum_{j_1=1}^r b_{1j_{1}}f_{j_1}, \dots, \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{\ell j_{\ell}}f_{j_\ell} \right)  = 
\\
\sum_{j_1=1}^r\cdots \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r (a_{1j_{1}} + kb_{1 j_1})\cdots a_{\ell j_{\ell}} \Phi\left(f_{j_1}, \dots,  f_{j_\ell} \right) = 
\\
\sum_{j_1=1}^r\cdots \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{1j_{1}}\cdots a_{\ell j_{\ell}} \Phi\left(f_{j_1}, \dots,  f_{j_\ell} \right)
\\ \qquad + 
k\Phi \sum_{j_1=1}^r\cdots \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r b_{1 j_1}\cdots a_{\ell j_{\ell}} \Phi\left(f_{j_1}, \dots,  f_{j_\ell} \right)=
\\ 
\Phi \left(\sum_{j_1=1}^r a_{1j_{1}}f_{j_1}, \dots, \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{\ell j_{\ell}}f_{j_\ell} \right)
\\ \quad
+ k \Phi \left(\sum_{j_1=1}^r b_{1j_{1}}f_{j_1}, \dots, \sum_{j_\ell=1}^r a_{\ell j_{\ell}}f_{j_\ell} \right),
$$
as desired.